# ValueError: X has 3 features per sample; expecting 1500

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, python-3.x

```py
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    '''
    For rendering results on HTML GUI
    '''
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    namequery = request.form['namequery']
    data = [namequery]
    vect = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
    my_prediction = model.predict(vect)
    return render_template('result.html',prediction = my_prediction)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

here is preprocessing of dataset code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
import string
import nltk
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pickle

data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
#removing id column
data=data.drop('id',axis=1)
string.punctuation
nltk.download('stopwords')
stopword=nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
def remove_punct(text):
  text_nopunct=''.join([char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation])
  return [word for word in text_nopunct.split() if word.lower() not in stopword]
x=data['text'].apply(remove_punct)
ps=nltk.PorterStemmer()
def stemming(text):
  text=[ps.stem(word)for word in text]
  return ' '.join(text)
x=x.apply(stemming)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=1500)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(x)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
y=data['target']
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)
# instantiate the model (using the default parameters)
logreg = LogisticRegression()

# fit the model with data
logreg.fit(X_train,y_train)

#
y_pred=logreg.predict(X_test)
from sklearn import metrics
cnf_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
cnf_matrix
class_names=[0,1] # name  of classes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
tick_marks = np.arange(len(class_names))
plt.xticks(tick_marks, class_names)
plt.yticks(tick_marks, class_names)
# create heatmap
sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(cnf_matrix), annot=True, cmap="YlGnBu" ,fmt='g')
ax.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.title('Confusion matrix', y=1.1)
plt.ylabel('Actual label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
# Saving model to disk
pickle.dump(logreg, open('model.pkl','wb'))

# Loading model to compare the results
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))
```

please help me someone to reslove this error. Iam new to machine learning am not understanding where i made mistake.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not so a fit transform while prediction. You should save the fit model in your preprocessing code for the tfidfvectorizer and use the same vectorizer while predicting.

Otherwise your vectorizer is learning new word representations and whose dimensions might not be 1500 what you have specified in your preprocessing code.

Comment: One only need transform on the test not fit transform.

Comment: thank you so much